# Как в создании модели добавить преобразование строки в число типа float?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Я новичок в питоне(за код не судите строго в основном до этого писал на с++ (в основном олимпиады)), и сейчас решил попробовать написать простую (точнее тупую) нейронку на питоне.
Использую tensorflow и keras.
На вход нейронке должен подаваться массив из 9 чисел и она должна распределять массив на 2 группы. Вот так я создаю массив:

```
   with open('yer_inf.txt', 'r') as f:
    c = []
    for line in f:
        c.append(float(line))
        if (len(c) == 9):
            b.append(c)
            # c.clear()
            c = []
    f.close()
data = np.array(b) #data.shape={664,9}
```

Вот так я задаю базовую модель:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(18, activation='relu', input_dim=9),
    layers.Dense(18, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')
])
```

Ну и у меня выдаётся ошибку при попытке model.fit():
Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported
Traceback (most recent call last). Но как задать преобразование я не могу найти в документации tensorflow.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Мне передавать надо именно числа

Comment: Нет уж, покажите весь релевантный код, включая `model.fit()`. Может у вас `target` строковый, а не `input`?